# selenium expectedconditions.visibilityofelementlocated POLLIING not working

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am using the Selenium 3.31 web driver.
I am waiting for an element to disappear from the page before the code moves on ( Code below)
What appears to be happing is that the code will wait for the entire 30 seconds, rather than "Poll" every 2 seconds to see if the condition is met (e.g move on)
So I am not sure if I have missed something here, but all I am simply trying to achieve is to waitUntil the "account_logout" div has disappeared.

Note I have used QTP / UFT for a long time , but Selenium is new to me , so I am not 100% if I need to set the FluentWait elsewhere or is it ok to just use the one with the java files ?

```
` //FluentWait
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
  .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("account_logout")));`
```

Comment: have you tried using FluentWait wait = new FluentWait(driver)?

Comment: As per your code, webdriver will poll every 2 seconds for total 30 seconds for the element to be invisible. Is that what you are looking for? If you are not sure update the question with what you are trying to achieve. Provide the HTML DOM as well along with Java Script code of element disappearing.

Comment: I am indeed trying to poll every two seconds for the "log out" link to disappear. Its a simple div with ID account_logout. I checked the dom after the next page had loaded , and there was no mention of the account_logout , bu still the code will hold for all 30 seconds, even though the element  is well gone after about 7 or 8 seconds. I would normally just check by the URL if I have logged out or not , but in this case , the URL remains the same, and no other elements change on the page... very weird I know..

Comment: I did try the ** FluentWait wait = ** code, but the same issue occurred.